# How to change the size of an element after each animation-iteratioin-count?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

> Suppose, I've animation from 0%{left: 0%;bottom: 0%;} to 100%{left: 100%; bottom: 0%;} and set animation-iteration-count to infinite.

Now when the animation **shifts to the end point (100%)** it starts again from **begin point (0%).** Now what I want is when animation begins again and again it should decrease the size of the element suppose the default size is `200 pixels width and 200 pixels height` so the decreasing vlaue equals minus 10 pixels and when the animated element becomes 0 pixels width and height it should again increase the size of that element so the increasing value equals plus 10 pixels.

This is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Tjvn/embedded/result/) without increasing and decreasing the element.

Comment: Is the element size known? meaning do you know that its size is going to become 0 after x number of iterations?

Comment: from 200px to 190px and 180px and 170px .... and last 0 px now the size should restart again 200px to 190px ,,,,

Answer (score 0):

This can be cleaned up, but essentially you can listen for `animationStart` to capture the initial size of your element,

```
$("#element").on("webkitAnimationStart", function(e) {
    var el = $(this);

    initialHeight = el.height();
    initialWidth = el.width();
});
```

...and listen for `animationIteration` to change the size of your element after every iteration:

```
$("#element").on("webkitAnimationIteration", function(e) {
    var el = $(this),
        currentHeight = el.height(),
        currentWidth = el.width(),
        scaleStep = 10;

    if (currentHeight > 0 && currentWidth > 0) {
        el.height(currentHeight - scaleStep);
        el.width(currentWidth - scaleStep);
    }
    else {
        el.height(initialHeight);
        el.width(initialWidth);
    } 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/8Tjvn/8/)**

Note that this would work in webkit browsers only. To support other browsers, take a look at the Browser Compatibility section in this article:

http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/

Comment: in the demo the size not even decreasing.

Comment: Are you using Chrome or Safari?

Answer (score 0):

If your browser supports steps() in the animation, and multiple animations, the you can go with a CSS only solution.

```
@keyframes esize
{
0%{left: 0%; bottom: 0%;}
100%{left: 90%; bottom: 0%;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes esize
{
    0%{left: 0%; bottom: 0%;}
  100%{left: 90%; bottom: 0%;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes shrink
{
    0%{width: 200px; height: 200px;}
  100%{width: 0px; height: 0px;}
}
@keyframes shrink
{
    0%{width: 200px; height: 200px;}
  100%{width: 0px; height: 0px;}
}

#element{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    animation: esize 3s infinite, shrink 60s steps(20,end) infinite;
    -webkit-animation: esize 3s infinite, shrink 60s steps(20,end) infinite;
}
```

I have made it slower so that you can see that the size change is done step by step, and not continously

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/8Tjvn/9/)